# Why there's a need to use the ampersand when getting a value from n format specifier?

Tags: c, syntax

Why there's a need to use the ampersand when getting a value from the n format specifier?

For example:

```
...
int n;
printf("%s: %nFoo\n", "hello", &n);
```

The `%n` is a [pointer to an integer type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hf4y5e3w.aspx)

And the ampersand is an address, so why does it convert the result from the format specifier to an integer in the example above?

Comment: I don't understand, it should return `n=5` in my code no? @wallyk

Comment: @kuhaku no, `n == 7`. Because of the `':'` and the `' '`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `%n` specifier gives the number of characters printed so far, so it's an output value, you add the `&` address of operator, to pass the address to the value of `n` so it can be modified inside `printf()` and when `printf()` returns, it has stored the number of characters in the `n` variable, by using a pointer to it.

An example of how to modify the value in a function is this

```
void setValue(int *where, int howMuch)
{
    if (where == NULL)
        return;
    *where = howMuch;
}

int main()
{
    int value;

    setValue(&value, 8);
    /*       ^ here is where the & address of is important */
    printf("%d\n", value);

    return 0;
}
```

and the output will be

```
8
```

Note that in c, there is no `passing by reference`, so the only way to modify the variable in a function is to pass it's address and access the pointer from the function.

Comment: How is it a number of characters printed so far if its type is a pointer to an integer? also why it won't work with passing `n` instead of `&n`?

Comment: Because as explained in the other answer, in c there is no such thing as passing parameters by reference. And in `main()` it's type is `int`, in `printf()` it's a pointer to integer, so dereferencing it like `*n` makes it of type `int`, and changing that value, changes the value in `main()` too.

Answer (score 1):

Function arguments in C are always values. Knowing the current value of the expression `n` would not give `printf` any information to store a new value there. What `printf` needs to know is *where* to store the result. That question is answered by a pointer, specifically, a pointer to the object in which you want the result stored, `n`.